# Get name of currently authenticated user

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmpp, google-talk

Is it possible to get the name of the currently authenticated user from the Google Talk XMPP API? I know that it's possible to get the name of your contacts by using [this](https://developers.google.com/talk/jep_extensions/roster_attributes?hl=en#3), but it doesn't return your name, just your contacts.

P.S. I'm using the [node-xmpp](https://github.com/astro/node-xmpp) module to connect with the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can request your own Vcard and get your name from the response when it was set before.
See: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0054.html

Example:

```
<iq id='get_vcard'        
    type='get'>
  <vCard xmlns='vcard-temp'/>
</iq>

<iq id='get_vcard'
    to='your_full_jid'
    type='result'>
  <vCard xmlns='vcard-temp'>
    <FN>Your Full Name</FN>
    <N>
      <FAMILY>Familiy Name</FAMILY>
      <GIVEN>Given Name</GIVEN>
      <MIDDLE/>
    </N>
    <NICKNAME>nickname</NICKNAME>
  </vCard>
</iq>
```

Comment: I think the 'to' address should be omitted, or set to your own bare JID, not the server's JID.